# How to handle CSRF in preflighted CORS POST request in django?

Tags: ajax, django, cors, csrf

I am trying to make `POST` request via AJAX from `abc.com` to URL from `xyz.com` (which is a Django application).
I am getting CSRF token by making a `GET` request to a URL on `xyz.com`, but the token changes when an `OPTIONS` request is made to `xyz.com` in the preflighted request.

Is there any way to get the response of `OPTIONS` request in the preflighted request ?

**Note:**

I am following instructions from following sources :

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: CSRF middleware aims to prevent what you wanna do. You need to hold cookies and send with every request you made. Or basically you could disable the middleware. By the way, modern browsers won't accept cross domain requests unless you have crossdomain.xml which allows other parties to make requests.

Comment: @scriptmonster I don't want to disable CSRF, I want a way to get CSRF token for explicitly validated origin.

Comment: @scriptmonster you are quite confused about cross origin communication.  Crossdomain.xml only applies to flash and java applets.  I suggest you read up on CORS at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS.

Comment: @vedarthk you have no access client side to the your server's response to the preflight.

Comment: For now I have made a work around in csrf middleware class, `OPTIONS` request will not refresh the token.

Comment: How are you doing the GET request, can you show code?  I think you'll need to ensure the GET is requested with credentials so that the server will return cookies.  These cookies are then sent back with the POST.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS, Requests with credentials

Comment: @AustinPhillips I have already went through all the documentation. I am not setting credentials value, by default it is `False` for CORS. According to my observations Cookies are not passed.

Comment: The Django csrf token has to be passed in a cookie for POST requests.  I think you'll need to do your requests with credentials irrespective of what the default is for CORS.

Comment: My previous comment is incorrect.  I've had another look at the [spec](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/cors/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#preflight-request) and cookies are not passed with OPTIONS preflight, even if withCredentials="true".  Consider the use of the https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers middleware on the Django site.

Comment: @AustinPhillips I have written my CSRF middleware by modifying Django's CSRF middleware. Everything works fine now.

Comment: @vedarthk... Can you share your middleware.. I am not able to get this working. The HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN header is different from what is inside the csrftoken cookie at the server. This only happens in the production server and not on localhost. Any insights?

Answer (score 5):

Django CSRF protection will allow OPTIONS requests, so no problem with the first stage:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-it-works

If I understand correctly, you then want the next request (e.g. a cross-domain POST) to be allowed through. For this to work and get past Django's CSRF protection, the request must send a CSRF token (in POST data or in header for AJAX) and a matching CSRF cookie.

Now, cross-domain restrictions make it impossible for abc.com to set or read a cookie for xyz.com, whether from javascript or from a server side response. Therefore, this approach is impossible.

Instead you will have to apply `@csrf_exempt` to the view. This would allow any site to post to it. Therefore, you'll need to build in some other protection to the view. You are, of course, on your own in checking the security of your protection. Remember that 'Referer' and 'Origin' headers can easily be forged with something as basic as curl.

Comment: I know that `OPTIONS` request is served by Django, but in that request the CSRF token is regenerated and I cannot catch that in pre-flighted request. This approach is not impossible, I was able to do that by modifying the middleware a bit which validates CSRF token without disabling CSRF protection.

Answer (score 2):

See [`django-cors-headers`](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/), you may find it how it works more suitable to solve your problem:

```
https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/
```

[Django-rest-framework recommends http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/ajax-csrf-cors](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/ajax-csrf-cors)

Comment: I have written my own middleware same as `django-cors-headers` (I was unaware of that).